# Integrating a differential form over a manifold that is not connected

Tags: integration, manifolds, differential-forms

For a problem on one of my homework sheets I have encountered the following kind of problem we did not discuss in class yet (or at least I don't think so).

Let's say we have differential form $\omega$ and a manifold $M$ given like
$$M := \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 |\; x^2+y^2 = 9, -1\leq z \leq 1\} $$
Then $\partial M$ consists of two circles (one at $z=1$ and one at $z = -1$). How do I then calculate
$$\int_{\partial M} \omega\enspace? $$

Normally I would parameterize $\partial M$ with a mapping $\varphi: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$. Then calculate the pullback $\varphi^{*}\omega$  by substituting $\varphi$ into $\omega$. The integral is then calculated as
$$\int_{\partial M}\omega = \int_{U}\varphi^{*}\omega\;. $$

But in this case $\partial M$ consists of two different manifolds (the two circles) which each would require a separate parameterization. How can a integral like this be calculated?

Comment: The lazy way would be to use Stokes theorem and compute $\int_M d\omega$

Comment: @quarague The homework mentioned above requires me to calculate $\int_{M}\mathrm{d}\omega$ once by using the definition of the integral and then again by using Stokes theorem. That's why I wrote the integral in my post in such a way that Stokes Theorem could easily be applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do essentially the same as in the connected case. You need two charts for the two components of the boundary and each of them becomes an integral over a circle. The most tricky bit is to get the orientation (ie the signs) correct.

**Edit:** For the orientations, what you want is that the orientation of the boundary plus an inward pointing normal (normal to the boundary and inward towards $M$) is the same as the orientation of $M$. In your example this means that projected to the $x,y$-plane one boundary circle is clockwise and the other one is counter-clockwise.

Comment: I guessed as much. Since I already know the final result by doing the connected case $\int_{M}\mathrm{d}\omega$, I could find out what the signs of the two integrals over these two circles should be. But this is exactly what doesn't make sense to me. I don't how I would figure out these signs otherwise. Our definition doesn't mention anything about orientations and how it is used when integrating.